# Prove that $S_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}c_{k}e^{ikx}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, exponential-sum

The problem is to prove that every trigonometric sum of the form
$$S_{n}(x) := \frac{1}{2}a_{0} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{k}\cos kx + b_{k} \sin kx)$$
can be expressed as 
$$S_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}c_{k}e^{ikx}$$
with $c_{k} := \frac{1}{2}(a_{k} - ib_{k})$
for $1 \leq k \leq n.$

Writing $e^{ikx} = \cos kx + i \sin kx$ did not help out, because I am stuck at dealing with $c_{k}$ for $-n \leq k \leq -1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Since $e^{ikx} = \cos kx + i \sin kx$ for all $k$, we have
$$\cos kx = \frac{1}{2} (e^{ikx} + e^{i(-k)x}).$$
Now, write the analogous expression for $\sin kx$, substitute in your expression for $S_n(x)$, and solve for the $c_k$ by collecting like terms.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I overlooked the relation $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})$!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

See this

$$ \sum_{k=-n}^{-1}c_{k}e^{ikx} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{-k}e^{-ikx}   $$